# Why is this sequence uniformly convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Reference: Conway - Functions of one complex variable p.167

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $g_n$ be a complex-valued continuous functions such that $\sum g_n$ converges absolutely and uniformly for $x$ in $X$.

Since $\sum g_n(x)$ convergrs uniformly for $x$ in $X$, there is an integer $n_0$ such that $|g_n(x)|<1/2$ for all $x$ in $X$ and $n>n_0$. This implies that $|log (1 + g_n(x))| \leq \frac{3}{2}|g_n(x)|$ and $Re(1+g_n(x))>0$ for all $x\in X$ and $n>n_0$. **Thus $\sum_{n=n_0+1}^ \infty log(1+g_n(x))$ converges uniformly for $x$ in $X$.**

Why does this assert that $\sum log (1+g_n(x))$ is uniformly convergent on $X$?

This does not seem to be necessary..

Answer (score 0):

Because
$|\log (1 + g_n(x))| 
\leq \frac32|g_n(x)|
$
so it converges uniformly
the same as
$\sum g_n(x)
$.

Comment: How so? It follows that $ ||log(1+g_n)||_\infty \leq 3/2 ||g_n||_\infty$, but uniform convergence of $\sum g_n$ does not gurantee the convergence of $\sum ||g_n||_\infty$.

Comment: You cannot simply do that. You need something like Dini's theorem..

Comment: Ambiguity:(1) If $\sum |g_n|$ converges uniformly, it's fine .(2)It can happen that $\sum g_n$ converges uniformly, and that $\sum |g_n|$ converges but not uniformly. E.g. with $X=[0,1]$ and $g_n(x)=(-1)^{n+1}(x^n-x^{n+1})$. So what does "converges absolutely and uniformly" mean?